# handle special characters in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a String with lots of special characters and emoji need to pass to a php, the special characters like & and []{}, causing error in php, I tried

replaceAll(new RegExp('&'), '%26');

to handle &, but there are lots of special characters cause error too, what is the best way to handle the special character that not causing any error in php?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Uri.encodeComponent](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Uri/encodeComponent.html):

```
Uri.encodeComponent('&'); // returns '%26'
```